# React-leaflet layers control toggle on/off all layers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

i have a dynamically generated layers list which is react-leaflet library component, i want to create layer button at the top of the list which will toggle on/off all other layers, i wanted to use onclick event and control it by my self but there no such event, so is there any way to do it somehow?

```
export const Points = ({
  points,
  setShowPointModal,
  setPointId,
  setIsEditPointMode,
  setComaprePointId,
  isPointsNonEditable,
  uniqueObjectTypes
}) => {
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setPointId(id);
    setIsEditPointMode(true);
    setShowPointModal(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <LayersControl position="topleft">
        {uniqueObjectTypes.map(el=>{
          return(<LayersControl.Overlay key={el.Object_Type_Id} checked name={el.Object_Type_Name}>
            <LayerGroup>
              {points.filter(poi=> poi.Object_Type_Id===el.Object_Type_Id).map(
              ({
                Id: id,
                coordinates,
                Name_object,
                Description: description,
                Image: image,
                emissions,
                owner_type,
                Environments
              }) => (
                <>
                  <Point
                    id={id}
                    key={id}
                    coordinates={coordinates}
                    Name_object={Name_object}
                    description={description}
                    image={image}
                    emissions={emissions}
                    owner_type={owner_type}
                    handleClick={handleClick}
                    setComaprePointId={setComaprePointId}
                    isPointsNonEditable={isPointsNonEditable}
                    EnvironmentAttachment={Environments}
                  />
                </>
              ))}
            </LayerGroup>
          </LayersControl.Overlay>)
        })}
      </LayersControl>
    </>
  );
};
```